# Ionic Android Internal Shared Memory

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm using [Ionic v1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4_KaplZHWAhUHsVQKHeF9BzcQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2Fdocs%2Fv1%2F&usg=AFQjCNGmidb2L_zbzbwN71ogNgXgwV9v7A) with [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) and [cordova email plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) to create a file and then attach it to a new email.  I have a working solution for iOS on any device, but I've come across a weird issue with Android.

[image: Android File System Layout]

When attempting to attach a file created in any internal storage location on Android (dataDirectory, etc), I receive "permission denied for attachment".  However, when I save the file to external storage, the attachment is successfully added.

I have published my application using external storage for Android, but unfortunately some of today's most popular devices don't have external storage.

Does anyone know a solution?  I've considered workarounds, such as uploading the file to a file-hosting service, and including a download link in the email.  I would use [$cordovaFileTransfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/), but I don't know if there would be permissions errors in internal storage.  I'd like to use a true email attachment if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: try to add the `cordova plugin file` plugin , what it does is it creates a directory and able to pick the file , so try to save your email `txt` file using this . and please do share your code how you are generating and sending the email

Comment: Check this question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153968/how-to-access-sdcard-files-in-ionic-3) only Internal storage can be accessed.

Comment: Check this question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153968/how-to-access-sdcard-files-in-ionic-3) only internal storage is accessed.

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is related to permission.
I have implemented this for file attachment to give a permission for file attachment try it hope this help you. Try this plugin `cordova.plugins.permissions`

```
 function checkPermission() {
            var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
            permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, checkPermissionCallback, null);
        }

function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
            $localStorage.StoragePermission = status.hasPermission;
            if (!status.hasPermission) {
                var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
                permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, null, null);                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the Issue is mainly related to the `Permission Issue` , before trying my second solution try to include this key in your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

From the [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-quirks) it states that :

> Previous versions of the plugin would choose the location of the
>   temporary and persistent files on startup, based on whether the device
>   claimed that the SD Card (or equivalent storage partition) was
>   mounted. If the SD Card was mounted, or if a large internal storage
>   partition was available (such as on Nexus devices,) then the
>   persistent files would be stored in the root of that space. This meant
>   that all Cordova apps could see all of the files available on the
>   card.
>
> If the SD card was not available, then previous versions would store
>   data under /data/data/, which isolates apps from each
>   other, but may still cause data to be shared between users.
>
> It is now possible to choose whether to store files in the internal
>   file storage location, or using the previous logic, with a preference
>   in your application's config.xml file. To do this, add one of these
>   two lines to config.xml:
>
> `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />`
>
> `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"
>   />`

**Solution 2:**

you can send file content in the `base64` , try to integrate [angular-base64](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) in your ionic-app and try to send the E-mail in the base64 format, here is the sample code :

```
$scope.tosendEmail= function(subject, message, file_content){
    var file = null;
    if(file_content != undefined){
        file = "base64:contact.vcf//"+$base64.encode(file_content);
    }

    var email_obj = {
      subject: subject,
      body: message,
      isHtml:false,
      attachments:file
    };

    cordova.plugins.email.open(email_obj);
}
```

So in this way you can send the attachments

Comment: I can't test either of the solutions this question received, since I'm not at my development computer, but I'm going to reward this solution with the bounty.  It provides an extra solution in case a permissions update doesn't work.  I'm upvoting both solutions (including Pritish) and marking the correct answer once I can test.